# Collapse rows to lowest complete row in each set

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I am cleaning a gigantic dataset, whcih came from using `tabulizer()` on a PDF.

The columns are correctly delineated, but I have many rows where one cell in the original was gigantic, and `tabulizer` read it as several rows, with all cells blank except the large one. I need to collapse the data frame so that rows are collapsed "down" to the lowest complete row.

Here is a sample of what the data look like:
[image]

As you can see, the column that these "extra rows" appear in varies by row (in one case it's `species`, in other cases it's `area.of.operation`. I want to collapse them to complete rows, such that row 1 remains intact, row 2 is actually rows 2:6 collapsed, row 7 is intact, etc. I don't even know if R is the best tool to use for this, but I would love if there is a `dplyr` solution. Example dataframe below.

Thank you in advance.

```
  mydata <-  structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
17L), target.species = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("", "hake", "hake, southern", "rosefish", 
"squid, cuttlefish,"), class = "factor"), gear = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("", "trawl, bottom", 
"trawl, midwater"), class = "factor"), number.boats = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("", "18 vessels", 
"98 refrigerated high", "none provided", "seas vessels"), class = "factor"), 
    company = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "not applicable"), class = "factor"), 
    area.of.operation = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("", "above provinces", "annual fishery; EEZ", 
    "concentrated around", "deepwater coastal"), class = "factor"), 
    species = structure(c(6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("Fur seal", "none provided", "otter", 
    "otter, river", "porpoise", "seal", "Seal", "South American Sea lion,", 
    "spectacled porpoise,"), class = "factor"), estimates = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "none"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: Can we assume that to-be-collapsed rows always have `target.species` missing for all but the last row? What do you expect to happen to rows 11 and 12?

Comment: @MauritsEvers unfortunately sometimes the target.species row also has additional info in it. For example, here row 7 should say, "squid, cuttlefish, rosefish" in the first column. Row 11 and 12 should be collapsed/merged with row 13.

It would be like searching for `complete.cases()` and then taking rows above that with many blanks and collapsing them into the complete row.

Answer (score 0):

The old `cumsum`-`split`-ting strategem with pasting each column with collapse="," and then `sub`-ing out the excess commas gets you most of the way:

```
t( as.data.frame(    # transpose because of the column oriented nature of R's apply returns
   lapply( split(mydata, cumsum( mydata$target.species != "")), 
       function(d){ sub(",.*,", ",", lapply( d, paste,  collapse=","))})))
   [,1]   [,2]             [,3]              [,4]                   [,5]              [,6]                                 
X1 "1,5"  "rosefish,"      "trawl,"          "18 vessels,"          "not applicable," "above provinces,annual fishery; EEZ"
X2 "6"    "squid,"         ""                "98 refrigerated high" ""                "concentrated around"                
X3 "7,12" "rosefish,"      "trawl,"          "seas vessels,"        "not applicable," "above provinces,concentrated around"
X4 "13"   "hake"           "trawl, midwater" "none provided"        "not applicable"  "above provinces"                    
X5 "17"   "hake, southern" "trawl, bottom"   "none provided"        "not applicable"  "deepwater coastal"                  
   [,7]                       [,8]   
X1 "seal,"                    "none,"
X2 "South American Sea lion," ""     
X3 "Seal,"                    "none,"
X4 "Fur seal"                 "none" 
X5 "none provided"            "none"
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. The `cumsum` - `split` strategy sort of works, but ends up losing data in the process (for example, "cuttlefish" has been lost from rows 6-7). I think I need to find a way to look for complete rows, then collapse anything above that with gaps down into the complete row.